# Android GIF transparent background disappears

Tags: java, android, gif

I'm new to Android Java programming. For a project I need transparent images, which change dynamically. I have created a layout with an ImageView. And in it a small GIF USA flag GIF with a transparent background.

[image]

In code I connect the variable to the imageview and assign the same image to the variable from the ImageResources

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listview_image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vlag);
```

This goes pretty well however the image is displayed with a white background. The transparency is lost. This is shown in the image below by the white background.

[image]

Comment: GIFs can be problematic. Let me suggest you converting it to PNG.

Answer (score 0):

GIF over ImageView are always an issue. Use [GIFImageView](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView)

And you must use it this way:

```
 gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.gifImageView);
 gifImageView.setBytes(bytes);
 gifImageView.startAnimation();
```

Even it has an option to download the gif from the web.

Comment: Same here, it provides a solution for Animation, not for Transparency.

Comment: Other solution would be to have each frame of the GIF (png files) and have an xml animation.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for Transparency, NOT for animation

Comment: Then, use PNG files if you don't want animation... if you want transparency AND animations, go for xml animations frame by frame. Using GIF for just transparency is pointless.

Comment: The images are in GIF. I have already tried a couple a GIF2PNG routines without succes. They all mess up the transparency.   :-(

Comment: Exists some software to extract each frame and those frames keep the transparency (even if is just 1 frame)